# Kubernetes stateful apps with bare metal

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am pretty new on Kubernetes and cloud computing. I am working with bare metal servers on my home (actually virtual servers on vbox) and trying to run a stateful app with StatefulSet. I have 1 master and 2 worker nodes and I am trying to run a database application on this cluster. So each node has 1 pod and I am very confused about volumes. I use `hostpath` volume(code below) but volumes working separately(actually they are not synchronizing). So my 2 pods are working different(same apps but they run like 2 different servers) when I reach them.

**How can I run that app in 2 synchronized pods?**

I've tried to synchronized volume files between 2 slaves. I also tried to synchronize volume files with deployment. I've tried to do this with volume provisioning (persistent volume and persistent volume provisioning).

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: cloud
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cloud
  serviceName: "cloud"
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cloud
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cloud
        image: owncloud:v2
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cloud-volume
          mountPath: /var/www/html/
      volumes:
      - name: cloud-volume
        hostPath:
          path: /volumes/cloud/
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: cloud
spec:
  selector:
    app: cloud
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
```

Comment: You would naturally expect a `hostPath` directory on different nodes to have different contents on each node: it is a "escape Kubernetes and directly publish this host directory into a container" mechanism with no other meaning, and doesn't imply any sort of cross-host replication.  It sounds like you might be looking for a (managed) [persistent volume supporting ReadWriteMany access](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes).

Comment: Can i do with a storage class ?

Comment: Think outside of Kubernetes for a moment. Read about `Glusterfs` and other network shared volume software solutions.

Comment: Have you any chance to take a look to NFS volumes in Kubernetes?

Comment: I know about NFS in Kubernetes.But my goal is creating a full available application.If NFS server down application will down.I actualy want if one of nodes would down other my application deploys on other node and resume from last state